# Why does try_convert return an XML validation error instead of null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an XML schema collection defined like this

```sql
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[DummySchema] AS 
N'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="dateofbirth" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'
```

I'm getting a set of XML values from a 3rd party service so I want to validate each value against an XML Schema. I am trying to do this using a set based approach so that I don't need to process each record by cursor with try/catch.

How do I check if XML is correct without going through all the set by cursor, trying to check each value on its own?

Assume I have this table

```sql
declare @xmlVals table
(
    stringVal nvarchar(1000)
);

insert into @xmlVals
values
(N'<person>
    <firstname>ErrorPersonName1</firstname>
    <dateofbirth>2000-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>'),
(N'<person>
    <lastname>ErrorPersonName2</lastname>
    <dateofbirth>2001-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>'),
(N'<person>
    <firstname>Valid FirstName</firstname>
    <lastname>Valid LastName</lastname>
    <dateofbirth>2002-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>')
```

Then I wrote this query

```sql
select iif(try_convert(xml([DummySchema]), stringVal) is null, 0, 1) as isValidXML
from @xmlVals
```

And I get this error

> (3 rows affected)
> Msg 6965, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
> XML Validation: Invalid content. Expected element(s): 'lastname'. Found: element 'dateofbirth' instead. Location: /*:person[1]/*:dateofbirth[1].

Expected result:

| isValidXML |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support XQuery `.Validate()` method.

I provided a link about that missing functionality in the T-SQL code comments below.

As an alternative, SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) has XML Task, operation Validation. It is very handy when you need to validate an XML file on the file system before it is loaded into SQL Server database.
Check it out here: [Validate XML with the XML Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/validate-xml-with-the-xml-task?view=sql-server-ver16)

In the meantime, please try the following workaround for T-SQL.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections 
                    WHERE name = N'DummySchema' 
                    AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo'))
   DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.DummySchema;

CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.DummySchema AS 
N'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="dateofbirth" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<person>
    <firstname>ErrorPersonName1</firstname>
    <dateofbirth>2000-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>'),
(N'<person>
    <lastname>ErrorPersonName2</lastname>
    <dateofbirth>2001-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>'),
(N'<person>
    <firstname>Valid FirstName</firstname>
    <lastname>Valid LastName</lastname>
    <dateofbirth>2002-01-01</dateofbirth>
</person>');

DECLARE @validationTbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, xmldata XML, Reason NVARCHAR(1024) NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM @tbl;

-- Method #1
DECLARE @ID INT, @XML AS XML(dbo.DummySchema)
   , @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl);

WHILE @RowCount > 0
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      SELECT @ID = ID, @XML = xmldata
      FROM @tbl
      ORDER BY ID DESC
      OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      INSERT INTO @validationTbl (ID, Reason)
      VALUES (@ID, ERROR_MESSAGE());  
   END CATCH

   SET @RowCount -= 1;
END;

-- test
SELECT t.*, vt.Reason 
FROM @tbl AS t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @validationTbl AS vt ON vt.ID = t.ID;


-- Method #2
-- unfortunately, it stops at the very first error
-- TRY_CAST() shall swallow all XSD validation errors internally
-- and produce a NULL value for all invalid rows
/*
Validate Expressions (XQuery)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/validate-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
*/
--SELECT *, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML(dbo.DummySchema)) AS Result
--FROM @tbl
--ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: thanks, it seems theres no other way to validate, i will use method #1